# How can I create a series switch with a transistor for low power application

Tags: transistors, switches

[image: battery sense block diagram]

Hi,

I would like to make a switch that turns on/off input Vbattery to a analog (AIN) pin of uController used to measure battery level.

The uC also should control if the transistor is providing the Vsense voltage to the uC.

I need the circuit to have the following properties.

1. When the transistor is OFF (i.e. not providing Vsense) then the current consumed by the transistor block should be not more than few micro amps.
2. When transistor is ON the output (that goes to the divided resistors) should follow the same voltage level as the V battery input. I can allow for a constant voltage drop between the input and output of the transistor as long as its fairly constant.
3. The on/off controller is TTL 0v/3.3v I don't mind which way is on or off.
4. The divider resistors are 1K ohm (more or less)

I am thinking that I will need some sort of FET but not sure what to use or how to create a circuit.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of this requirement on this site. Use the search bar and enter a few key words like battery monitor that can be turned off or disabled.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/343435/low-power-battery-voltage-monitor

Comment: After looking at more examples I am also open to a digital voltmeter IC, any suggestions would be great.

Comment: @BerabenSystems How much resolution into the supply voltage do you need? Are you just trying to decide if it is 2 V or else 6 V? Or some finer-grained resolution?

Comment: @jonk I want to measure the battery level so perhaps  50mV would be the most coarse resolution. I would try and target 10mV resolution if I can. The battery data would be measured and send to the server with other telemetry data.

Comment: I am now thinking I can do with with an opamp but It would require another DC-DC step up converter. I will do this if I have too but I would be nice if I had and all in one IC>

Comment: @BerabenSystems How thermally stable must your measurement be? How replicable must it be from instrument to instrument? Or do you plan to calibrate each case for vagaries? I need a lot more information and careful thought than I've seen so far. Others perhaps don't need details. But I do. I'll back away until I see the larger picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a digital output to turn on the voltage divider so that it only uses power when you want to read it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f86a3H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>