# How bad would it be to voltage divide 9 V to <3 V?

Tags: batteries, voltage-divider

To my application using the ESP32 I want to add a simple voltage divider to check the power level from my 9 V battery.

I use a 9 V battery because it's available and if I were to make it a commercial product I don't want to use Li-po.

The ESP32 isn't 5 V pin safe, so I have to get it below 3 V. Using a [voltage divider calculator](https://ohmslawcalculator.com/voltage-divider-calculator) I can use 4k7 for R1 and 2k2 for R2 and get the voltage down to 2.87 V, safe enough for the MCU.
I then do an analog read and check the input to determine the status of the battery.

But how bad is it for the lifespan of the battery to pull it down from 9 V to 2.87 V (if at all)? What are the consequences?

Sticking to alkaline the other option is to find a battery holder that holds enough volts to power the MCU. 4 x 1.5 V would do the trick, I would then only need to divide it from 5 V to <3 V. Thoughts?

Comment: It's darned hard to find any good ADC info on "ESP32" (which isn't so much a device as a group of similar things.) I believe it uses a 12-bit SAR and these should have perhaps no more than about 2.5 k Ohm driving source impedance. As Kuba suggests, you can get the current load on the 9 V battery down by increasing the resistor values. But I remain curious about what that may imply for your readings.

Comment: Always take 3 ADC samples and discard the one with the largest deviation. The ADC is periodically lying.

Comment: Do you want to _check_ the power level on your 9V battery, or do you want to _power your system_ from that 9V battery?

Comment: One way to minimize the drain on the battery is to use a MOSFET or SSR to connect the voltage divider only for a short time to take the measurement.

Comment: see also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472697/how-can-i-create-a-series-switch-with-a-transistor-for-low-power-application/472818#472818c for a way  to turn the voltage divider off when it's not needed.

Comment: @Jens, *The ADC is periodically lying* How so?

Comment: @TonyM In my evaluation boards I observe a noise of +/- 6 LSB in the ADC results when I use a source impedance of 10 kohm and 100nF to GND at the ADC input directly soldered to the module (no breadboard) and 47uF ceramic across the 3.3V. But some single samples during a second are far off from the correct value. I wrote a filter, that throws out these artefacts and replaces them with the mean value of the adjacent values. So a software decision, taken from a single conversion result, may be wrong.

Comment: @Jens, ah, so you really mean that the ADC is fine but that bad/constrained design in the ADC circuit may cause erroneous ADC results? In other words, it's caused by a circuit problem, not an ADC problem.

Comment: @TonyM Yes, it seems to be an MCU internal crosstalk, probably from the RF section, I will report if I am sure about the source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The battery only cares about the current, not about what you do with it. So, R1+R2 in series are too low of a value. It's 7k total, so per Ohm's law, they drain more than 1mA from a 9V battery. From the point of view of the battery, you have a 7k equivalent resistance from (+) to (-).

Instead, multiply both values by the same factor between 10x and 20x, and put a 1uF ceramic capacitor across R2.

That will cut down the current to 50-100uA, and that should be more reasonable given the power consumption of ESP32.

See also [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/472697/10810) for a circuit that can turn off the voltage divider when its output is not actively used to measure battery voltage. Ideally, to conserve power, you'd want to implement something like that.

Comment: If you're willing to invest one more part, you could put a cheap op-amp in voltage follower configuration at your voltage divider's output and raise the voltage divider values even further, up into the hundreds of kOhms, which might be helpful in a battery-powered application.

Comment: Be careful with the op-amp buffer! They often come with an in this context significant quiescent current, more then negating the gains from decreased voltage divider current.