# Debugging implementation of low current battery monitor

Tags: arduino, voltage-divider, debugging

I have tried to implement the circuit in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/64491/62613) in order to measure the voltage of an external battery using an Arduino. However, I am not sure if I have wired it correctly. Here is the diagram:

[image: low current battery monitoring circuit]

And here is my implementation:

[image: my broken circuit]

I have redrawn the circuit to match the layout above:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuczU4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage divider should in theory drop the voltage of the battery from 4.2v to 3.22V. When I measure the voltage with the multimeter as shown, the voltage measured is 3.64V. When I measure the voltage between the middle of the divider and the Arduino's GND I get -0.37V. In both cases measurements are made when PIN 8 is set to HIGH. With the pin set to LOW, the voltage across the divider drops to 0.

First question: does it make sense to use this kind of circuit to measure the voltage of a battery that is not actually powering the Arduino itself?

Second question: Assuming I eventually power my MCU with the battery, will this circuit work correctly?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a connection from the battery ground to the Arduino GND

Comment: Wow, thanks that seems to have fixed it. I thought I had tried connecting the two grounds but I must have done it wrong. I now get a 3.15V reading from the multimeter and a 3.09V from the Arduino's analog input which is much closer to expected values.